# How to update a value without needing to double click on button? React

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

For my number game project I want the new value thats been calculated to show in a single click on the buttons. But for now I need to click on the same button twice in order for the new value to show. How can i make the update in a single click?

The one I wish to be updated:

```
<p>Current guess: <strong>{Math.round(this.state.guess)}</strong></p>
```

**My buttons:**

```
<button onClick={this.Higher.bind(this)}> Higher </button>
<button onClick={this.Lower.bind(this)}>Lower</button>
```

**Their methods:**

```
Higher() {
  this.setState({
    min: this.state.guess,
    max: this.state.max,
    guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2)
  });
};

Lower() {
  this.setState({
    max: this.state.guess,
    min: this.state.min,
    guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2),  
  }); 
};
```

I suspect that the first click initiates the calculation and the second click calls the result.

I'm new to ReactJS and want to learn by remaking some old C# projects in ReactJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem actually lies in your 'guess' calculation logic - the rest of your code looks fine.

```
Higher() {
  const newMin = this.state.guess;
  const newGuess = (newMin + this.state.max) / 2;
  this.setState({
    min: newMin,
    guess: newGuess    
  });
}

Lower() {
  const newMax = this.state.guess;
  const newGuess = (this.state.min + newMax) / 2;

  this.setState({
    max: newMax,
    guess: newGuess      
  });
}
```

FYI, it's also better practice to do your `.bind()` in the constructor, not in the render -- this means it will only run once. [See this blog post for more information](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).

It's also worth noting that you don't need to update a state value if the value is the same as the current state. `setState` does a deep merge of state anyway, so you only need to pass the changed data.

i.e.

```
this.setState({
   min: newMin,
   max: this.state.max // No need for this!
});
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/0ya729r4/7/

Answer (score 0):

setState is async so it won't work as expected. What you can do is to call setState again passing a callback.

```
 Higher() {
    this.setState({
        min: this.state.guess,
        max: this.state.max,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2)
      }
    });
}
Lower() {
    this.setState({
       max: this.state.guess,
       min: this.state.min,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2),
      }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand setState properly..

setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

[More reference about setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
            min:state.guess,
            max:state.max,
            guess: ((state.min + state.max) / 2)
}));
```